# Determine vector of spin in Proca equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, quantum-spin

We have Proca field $A_\mu$ that has 4 components and obeys the following equation (with Lorentz gauge)

$\square A^\mu+m^2A^\mu=0$

This equation has plane wave solution

$A_\mu=a_\mu e^{ik^\nu r_\nu}$

Such that

$k_\nu k^\nu=m^2$

And

$A_\mu=a_\mu e^{-ik^\nu r_\nu}$

One can be considered as particle solution and another as antiparticle.

In fermion case we have 2 types of solutions - spin up and spin down. Massive Proca bosons should have 3 states (+1, 0, -1 spin) and massless only +1 and -1.

What are the solutions of Proca equation that describe state with spins +1, 0 and -1?